# Package pgfkeys Error. What does it mean'

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/5'

I keep receiving this error at the "\end{axis}" line although I don't see where the mistake is.

```
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-1,5, xmax=2,5, ymin=-1, ymax=2,samples=100,grid=minor]
        \addplot[black, thin](x,0);
        \addplot[blue, thick](x,x - x^2);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

\end{document}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2.5 instead of 2,5 and 1.5 instead of 1,5:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-1.5, xmax=2.5, ymin=-1, ymax=2,samples=100,grid=minor]
        \addplot[black, thin](x,0);
        \addplot[blue, thick](x,x - x^2);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]